# How can i implement a treetable in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, treetable

I want to implement a tree table in Angular 9. I was trying but I couldn't. Can anyone help me to implement a tree table in Angular 9?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    (<any>$)( document ).ready(function() {
      (<any>$)('.tree').treegrid({
      'initialState': 'collapsed',
      'saveState': true,
      expanderExpandedClass: 'fa fa-minus',
      expanderCollapsedClass: 'fa fa-plus'
      });
  });   

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  title = 'jquery-treetable';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<table class="tree">
    <tr class="treegrid-1">
        <td>Root node</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-2 treegrid-parent-1">
        <td>Node 1-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-3 treegrid-parent-1">
        <td>Node 1-2</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-4 treegrid-parent-3">
        <td>Node 1-2-1</td><td>Additional info</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Style and JS file**

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "node_modules/jquery-treegrid/css/jquery.treegrid.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-treegrid/js/jquery.cookie.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-treegrid/js/jquery.treegrid.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-treegrid/js/jquery.treegrid.bootstrap3.js"
            ]
```

**Output**

```
Root node   Additional info
Node 1-1    Additional info
Node 1-2    Additional info
Node 1-2-1  Additional info
```

**Error shows in console**

[image: Error shows in console]

Comment: try this plugin i have developed this https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tree-table

Answer (score 0):

You can find the typical requirements and accessibility consideration for the tree treegrid in the [WAI Authoring practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#treegrid).

In my humble opinion, if you are doing it for the commercial software, I **strongly** advise using some third party component.

If the purpose is education - get some Angular, TypeScript, CSS and HTML knowledge first.